# Minikube for Ubuntu 20.04 WSL stuck on 'Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...' after minikube start and 'StartHost failed' error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, ssh

I've come across the following problem where my minikube cluster doesn't start and the command line becomes stagnant in the following way:

```
$ minikube start
�  minikube v1.17.1 on Ubuntu 20.04
�  Kubernetes 1.20.2 is now available. If you would like to upgrade, specify: --kubernetes-version=v1.20.2
✨  Using the docker driver based on existing profile
�  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
�  Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...
```

This all started after running `minikube stop` and then `minikube start` again after troubleshooting a [kube-prometheus-stack](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) helm release's pods not running. I've tried restarting my Docker daemon, rebooting my computer, searching online of course, and do see the minikube docker container created just after running `minikube start` despite the "StartHost failed" error and being stuck on updating the running docker container. I am not connected to a VPN, though I use one often.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about your user privileges to run docker containers?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if complete reinstall is a valid option for you, but for me this helped:

1. `sudo minikube delete`
2. After delete is finished, `minikube start` again